# Python can't assign to operator

Tags: python

I keep getting SyntaxError:

> can't assign to operator when trying to assign a ID

Working Code

```
canvas = self.matrix.CreateFrameCanvas()
graphics.DrawText(canvas, font, LEFT, TOP, setcolor, MESSAGE)
self.matrix.SwapOnVSync(canvas)
```

What I am trying to achieve

```
ID = "4"
canvas+ID = self.matrix.CreateFrameCanvas()
graphics.DrawText(canvas+ID, font, LEFT, TOP, setcolor, MESSAGE)
self.matrix.SwapOnVSync(canvas+ID)
```

Error:

```
canvas+ID = self.matrix.CreateFrameCanvas()
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `canvas+ID`?

Comment: I am trying to create multiple canvas on a led matrix panel by assigning each canvas with a unique ID... so canvas1 canvas2 canvas3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to programatically assign multiple variables like `canvas4` and/or `canvas5` and so on, you should probably be using a list or dictionary, *not* multiple variables.

How about something like:

```
canvases = {}
ID = 4

canvases[ID] = self.matrix.CreateFrameCanvas()
graphics.DrawText(canvases[ID], font, LEFT, TOP, setcolor, MESSAGE)
self.matrix.SwapOnVSync(canvases[ID])
```

Answer (score 1):

The operator `+` is used to concatenate strings, not variable names. although what you want can be done by using `eval('canvas'+ID+'= self.matrix.CreateFrameCanvas()')` it is a terrible practice, use a list instead.